# OSGI Apache Felix IPOJO : Annotations or pure MAVEN?

Tags: maven, osgi, ipojo

I'm jumping in OSGI with FELIX IPOJO. According to the tutorials there are two approaches possible:

- use annotations to define services and entry points.  FELIX jar's are added more or less manually.
- use the MAVEN approach and define services and entry points in pom.xml

Am I free to choose ? Are there pro's and con's ?

Thanks for any hint ! 
Gerry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are free to choose, but I would recommend the annotation providing an easier development model. The pure XML approach was made initially to support Java 1.4.

Comment: Just another concern: FELIX needs some some additional bundles from IPOJO (e.g.org.apache.felix.ipojo.*, org.apache.felix.ipojo.arch* ). 

Now does this dependency fixes me on a FELIX compatible container ? 

What will happen if I have to deploy, lets say to a KARAF server ( ok, Karaf contains felix ... , bad example.), but there are other OSGI JAVA runtimes out there.
Do these IPOJO bundles always have to be delivered ?

Thx
Gerry

Comment: No. iPOJO is a subproject of the Apache Felix project. The Felix Framework is also a subproject of the Apache Felix project. They do not depend on each other.